# Font Gregor on Mozilla

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, cross-browser, mozilla

Font Gregor is cut on Mozilla.

You can see how it looks on Chrome:

[image]

And on Mozilla:

[image]

Have some ideas how to fix that?

UPD: Here is code guys
**HTML**`

```
  <div id="headliner" class="constraint-wrapper">
       <div class="constraint-box">
             <div id="headline">

    <span>«Русская Тоскания» в 2016 году</span>
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here is **CSS** for all:

```
#headliner{
width:100%;
height:140px;

.constraint-wrapper {
width:100%;
display:flex;
justify-content: center; 
.constraint-box {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    max-width:1200px;
    padding:15px;
}
}
```

And

```
#headline {
word-wrap:break-word; 
font-family: 'Gregor', Arial;
font-size: 35px;
color: #9a0e2f;
white-space: nowrap;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: 60px;
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    font-size:19px;



 }
 }  `
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Apparently, Mozilla doesnt support .otf. I went to off.site of font Gregor. To my surprise there is no any others formats, so I googled and found it on the other site and took it right from console.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know exactly without full code examples. It looks fine in all browsers on this website: http://gregorfont.com/  - this leads me to believe you have some set height in CSS causing overflow to be cut off?

Comment: height is 100%.

Comment: @RatiborYaroslavovich cool, please update your post with a [mcve] so that we can actually see this happen rather than showing it just as picture.

Comment: I added. Please check.